# Последовательное выполнение SetTimeout()

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Решился сделать анимацию с плавной сменой фона у блока. Пробовал сначала в CSS через **keyframe** но не получил нужный результат а именно после каждых 10 секунд сделать плавную смену фона за 0.5 секунды. Решил использовать **SetTimeout()**

```
function bgOne() {cont.removeClass(one).addClass(two)};
    function bgTwo() {cont.removeClass(two).addClass(three)};
    function bgThree() {cont.removeClass(three).addClass(four)};


    setTimeout(bgOne, 5000);
    setTimeout(bgTwo, 5000);
    setTimeout(bgThree, 5000);
```

где *one*, *two*, *three*, *four* -  переменные содержащие CSS клас с нужным фоном;
а  *cont* - элемент DOM дерева

После 5 секунд с загрузки страницы выполнились сразу **все SetTimeout()**

**Вопрос, как заставить их выполняться последовательно только после окончания предыдущего?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну можно просто дописать вызов следующей функции - внутри предыдущей. Цепочка вызовов:

```
setTimeout(bgOne, 5000);

function bgOne() {
  cont.removeClass(one).addClass(two);
  setTimeout(bgTwo, 5000);
}

function bgTwo() {
  cont.removeClass(two).addClass(three);
  setTimeout(bgThree, 5000);
}

function bgThree() {
  cont.removeClass(three).addClass(four);
  setTimeout(bgOne, 5000);
  /* Например третья может вызвать снова первую - пойдет бесконечный цикл */
}
```

Хотя на самом деле можно делать одну функцию, названия классов хранить в массиве и переключать классы по индексу:

```js
let bubu = ["one", "two", "three", "four"];
let i = 0;

let int = setInterval(function() {
  let next = (i + 1) % bubu.length;
  console.log("Remove: " + bubu[i], "/// add: " + bubu[i = next]);

  // if( ??? ) clearInterval(int);
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Сработало как и хотелось. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: tomato;
  animation: changeBackground 40s infinite;
}

@keyframes changeBackground {
  0%, 20% {
    background-color: tomato;
  }
  
  25%, 45% {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
  
  50%, 70% {
    background-color: lightgreen;
  }
  
  75%, 95% {
    background-color: crimson;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function bgOne() {console.log('bgOne')};
function bgTwo() {console.log('bgTwo')};
function bgThree() {console.log('bgThree')};


setTimeout(() => {
  bgOne();
  setTimeout(() => {
    bgTwo();
    setTimeout(() => {
      bgThree();
    }, 2000);
  }, 2000);
}, 2000);
```

Надо ещё через промисы подумать как сделать, чтоб с async/await можно было заюзать. А то громоздкач конструкция.

Answer (score 2):

```js
/**
 * @param args - {func, timeout}
 */

function startTimeouts(...args) {
  let iterator = queue(args.flat(Infinity));
  iterator.next();

  function* queue(args) {
    for (let currentTimeout of args) {
      yield setTimeout(() => {
          currentTimeout.func();
          iterator.next();
        }, currentTimeout.timeout);
    }
  }
}


startTimeouts(
  {func() {console.log(0)}, timeout: 0},
  {func() {console.log(1)}, timeout: 1000},
  {func() {console.log(2)}, timeout: 500},
  {func() {console.log(3)}, timeout: 500},
  {func() {console.log(4)}, timeout: 1500},
);

startTimeouts(
  [{func() {console.log(0)}, timeout: 0},
  {func() {console.log(1)}, timeout: 1000},
  {func() {console.log(2)}, timeout: 500},
  {func() {console.log(3)}, timeout: 500},
  {func() {console.log(4)}, timeout: 1500}]
);
```